# SuperUser Installation -> PIE executables only

Tags: rooting, root-access

I have a phone in development mode (not just the tap 5 times thing, I have the `ro.debuggable=1` etc.), and I need to install a SuperUser. I have Android 5.1 (Stagefright update). I have access to /system through `adb remount`. Is there a `su` binary that PIE-only devices support?  SuperSU does not work, I get this error:

> 127|root@j6010_blu_82:/data/local # ./su error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported

I am a (web) dev ("Ha you can't compile :("), I know how my phone's warranty is gonna be invalid, and how if the phone blows up it's not your fault :)

Comment: You could try this one that has recent updates: https://superuser.phh.me/

Comment: I am not using a nexus phone or any phone listed there I am using a BLU STUDIO X PLUS

Comment: @ThePROgrammer Don't worry about the other models, just use the main superuser.zip there.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you resolve it ?